# How to fix the duplicate header row at a zoom level of 200% when we start scroll in SSRS report preview

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

Duplicate header row is seen when I start scrolling down the SSRS report after adding FixedData as true for the static header in a tablix.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6Dvb.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue, with SSRS report zoom as 150% or 200% (not browser zoom), the floating header started before the original header section scrolled up..
With 100% zoom, the header works fine while scrolling.